Identify set: "dino ambush" with orange car
Kid brought lego set with front of box but no code to search instructions. Anyone know what this may be?
It’s called Dino Park Dino Ambush. No luck online. Orange car with opening blue windshield roof. And Dino on a trailer.

Your kid didn't buy any Lego - they bought from a clone brand named "Block Tech" instead (a brand owned by RMS international).
After a bit of searching, I found a matching set on ebay:

Apparently it has been reissued as "pen transport" with a different box:

Alas, as most clone brands, RMS do not keep catalogs of their sets, nor downloadable instructions. You might have some luck if you write them an email.
